# Display data using pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables which users and groups and I also has created a pivot table for them.
What I want to display is list of the group that user have not joined yet.

my controller

```
public function redirectFunct()
    {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $groups=Group::all();
            $exists = DB::table('group_user')
            ->whereuser_id(Auth::user()->id)
            ->count() > 0;
       
           
            return view('member.dashboard',['user'=>$user,'groups'=>$groups,'exists'=>$exists]);
        }
```

blade file

```
@foreach($groups as $groups)
              @if($!exists)
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$groups->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$groups->groupName}}</td>
                    <td>{{$groups->groupDesc}}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary .btn-{color}">Details</button></td>
                    <td><a href="{{url('/join',$groups->id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary .btn-{color}">Join</button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              @endif
              @endforeach
```

I do not sure how to check if the data is exist or not in the pivot table. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this in your `$exist` I'm not sure what `->count() > 0;` is use for

```
$exists = DB::table('Group')
            ->where('userID', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```

If you want to display only the group that the `user` doesn't exist in `group` you could try this

```
<tbody>              
@foreach($groups as $group)
    @if('your group parent id' != 'your user id that related to the group')
        <td>{{$group->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$group->groupName}}</td>
        <td>{{$group->groupDesc}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary .btn-{color}">Details</button></td>
        <td><a href="{{url('/join',$groups->id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary .btn-{color}">Join</button></td>
    @endif
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: Could add the `dd($exists, $groups, $user)` output in your controller?

Comment: I am very sorry but i dont understand what you want, i am new to laravel :')

Comment: ah no worries in bellow `$exists = ...` add `dd($exists, $groups, $user)` then refresh the page it will show some text, then tell me what the text are

Comment: ^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#819 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
^ Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1446 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▶]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}

Comment: how you want me to share the whole text?

Comment: if can send a screenshot of it

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
this is the screenshot of that page

The pivot table

[image]

Comment: can you click the `attributes` and send the updated screenshot as well as in ` {#1446 ▼ #items: array:2 [▶] #escapeWhenCastingToString: false } ` the 2 item

Comment: On the top there the 2 item one with `#items: array:2 [▶] #escapeWhenCastingToString: false` click it then send the screenshot aswell

Comment: now click one of the group then screenshot it `attributes` as well

Comment: Click the `attributes` like the `user` one and screenshot its `data`

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer try it out

Comment: it show the list of groups but also the group that user have joined :') not what i want which is display the group that user have not joined yet.

Comment: I see than could you tell me what the `relationship` of your `user` and `group` is?

Comment: belongsToMany relationship

Comment: then what `value` or `id` name does the `user` tell us it belongs to what `group`

Comment: did you mean the pivot table? i already put the picture of that table above

Comment: I have updated my answer in your blade `@foreach` it can use the same parameter it must be `@foreach($groups as $group)` not `@foreach($groups as $groups)`

Comment: it shows error (Object of class App\Models\Group could not be converted to int)

Comment: ah I change it again there's a typo

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here, my bad. `$group->userID` is id for user who create the group. so i dont think i can call the variable that way because the user that i mentioned above is for group member.